# How to apply a function to option selected tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have the following dropdown:

```
    <select id="role" name="role" class="form-control">
      <option selected>Choose an option</option>
      {% for index, value in roles_form.fields.roles.choices %}
          <option value="{{ index }}">{{ value }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

And I have a function that show and hides another div when the user chose between the options:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
      var developer = {{ developer_id }};
      var value = $(this).val();
      console.log(developer);

      if (value == developer) {
        $('#github_link').show();
      } else {
        $('#github_link').hide();
      }
})
```

So, when the user choose `Developer` the div remains shown, and when they choose any other option this div hides. Everything works fine, but there's a thing, when the page loads this tag: `<option selected>Choose an option</option>`mantain the div shown, and that's not correct, when the page loads the div needs to be hidden too.

However I'm not pretty sure how to add that to the function, any thoughts?

Comment: Can't you simply run `$('#github_link').hide();` on page load

Comment: you can hide it manually using display property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your issue is that you want this logic to run on page load, as well as on change, then you can simply trigger it.

```
$(...).on('change', ...).trigger('change');
```

`trigger` will cause the event handler to execute immediately.

Comment: I do not think it would be necessary to trigger a change via Javascript. Since it needs to be hidden initially, it is better to add a style or class to it.

Comment: I would agree that ideally the initial state of the elements should be set without the need for javascript.  However, this method is available.

Comment: Your statement is valid, but the solution is second-best. Since it is correct, I did not down-vote it. Since it is second-best, I did not upvote it and written my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add

```
style="display: none;"
```

into the tag which has the `github_link` `id` when you define it in the HTML. Showing it and hiding it will work.

It is more elegant though to define a CSS `class` like:

```
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

and use `addClass`/`removeClass` to hide/show the tag, since, as far as I know, `show()` and `hide()` are not the fastest features in jQuery:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
      var developer = {{ developer_id }};
      var value = $(this).val();
      console.log(developer);

      $("#github_link")[((value == developer) ? "remove" : "add") + "Class"]("invisible");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

your script loads when your select being changed, so to make it works when the page loads, you need to have it outside any event

```
var developer = {{ developer_id }};

$('select').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  console.log(developer);

  if (value == developer) {
    $('#github_link').show();
  } else {
    $('#github_link').hide();
  }
})

// Outside any events as well

var value = $('select').val();

if (value == developer) {
    $('#github_link').show();
} else {
    $('#github_link').hide();
}
```

or to make it simpler, we can have it inside a function:

```
var developer = {{ developer_id }};

function fName(value){
    if (value == developer) {
         $('#github_link').show();
    } else {
        $('#github_link').hide();
    }
}

$('select').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(developer);

    fName(value)
});
fName($('select').val());
```